# lift don't rewrite the value

Tags: scala, lift

is there a way, how to bind a `SHtml.submit` tag to a `<lift:tag/>` and preserve the `value` attribute? I know that there is a way how to conserve all others, using `-%>` instead of `->`, but what can I do if I rather want to write the value in snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CSS Selector Transforms, then you can do:

```
"type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmit(s => println("Dude... the value is "+s))
```